# How are logic gates designed?

Tags: logic-gates

I know what are logic gates and how to deal with them, and how they are so important in computer architecture. I learnt logic gates combinations and how they work.

Now I would like to know how are those gates designed?

What are the electronic components used to make a logic gate?

I just know some electricity basics!

Comment: A course in spelling, capitalization and grammar might also be useful (nobody's perfect of course).

Comment: @Andyaka how this could help me ? my language is bad is this mockery ?

Comment: Your quotation from the Quran appears to be in good order so you must ask yourself why I have made this remark.

Comment: @Andyaka how this relevant to my question ?

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi trying to solve your misunderstanding: Andy is not mocking your language. He's just saying that you've shown you can do better than adding "..." everywhere, which mean nothing. And you can probably use that knowledge to more clearly structure your question, so that we understand it. That is *very* relevant to your question, because without us being able to understand your question, we can't answer it. It seems to be very general; in fact, too general to be answered. But maybe you have something more specific in mind, and all the text that is *actually* irrelevant to your …

Comment: … question is just distracting us and yourself. This is an engineering site, so you don't have to thank us, be glad, explain what you've learned the last years in which order or add "!" after every sentence. Just ask a *clearly defined*, *precise* question that you can't better answer yourself through literature!

Comment: It is relevant to the question since we can't even actually *understand* you. For example, when reading your first sentences, it seems like you *already know* logic gates, flip-flops, machine language, and assembly. Then, you ask what are logic gates. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MarcusMüller okey thank you , i will edit it now 
dim : i get the point !
Andy : sorry for misunderstanding but still don't know what is the point about my quotation

Comment: @dim any answer now ?

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi That's better. I removed my downvote. I'll make the few more cosmetic edits required myself, and hopefully, you'll get some answers.

Comment: @dim maybe describing what i know about assembly and such things is Without avail !

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi Actually, I can't make the edits, I still feel there is something wrong when you mention RAM/memory. Logic gates do not really "give us very important ram". Maybe you should just remove this part. You just want to know how logic gates are implemented in silicon, right?

Comment: The point about the quotation is that your wording and language use was good whereas your wording and language use is poor for your question and this looks like cell-phone laziness.

Comment: @Andyaka it's quran did you think i translate it mayself ? 
this is  hard even for native english speakers .. !
see this :
http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1993/why-are-there-different-translations-of-the-quran?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi I can't fully agree with dim that's all better now – you say "I learnt logic gates […] and how they work.", and then ask "how are those gates designed?". That's a contradiction!

Comment: @MarcusMüller i learned how to use them without learn what they are from scratch ! i learned just what they do ( results  )

Comment: Come on people. Sure the original question was fairly poor English, the edits have improved it a lot. But what he was asking was perfectly clear from the start. The point is to answer electronics questions not to complain about peoples language skills. I'm sure he did a far better job of asking the question in English than most of you could do answering it in his native language.

Comment: @MarcusMüller "how they work" applies to "logic gates *combinations*". Not just "logic gates". I think it's rather clear now. It could be considered broad, but not unclear. But feel free to improve edits if you think it's not.

Comment: @Andrew Indeed, we certainly all had the right idea of what he was asking from the start. But look: now, the question is a lot better. No more inconsistencies, no more fuzziness. Wasn't it worth it? OP learnt some electronics *and* the right way to ask questions.

Comment: @dim I agree that the edits were worth it. But the somewhat confrontational style of the comments was unnecessary and were in no way required in order to make those edits.

Comment: @Andrew I disagree with you when you say the question was perfectly clear from the start - it certainly was not - it held contradictions that made it a bad question and, who was complaining about language skills? Do you see my observations as complaints (because they are not). I find your comment largely irrelevant (now that might be considered a complaint)!

Answer (score 1):

The three basic building blocks are NAND, NOR and NOT gates.

You can build any logic gate you want from 2 input NAND or NOR gates. e.g. A NOT gate is a NAND gate with the two inputs connected together. An OR gate is a NAND gate with NOT gates on both inputs.

When it comes to building them just about all digital logic is these days is made of CMOS FET transistors. A NOT gate takes two transistors, a NAND gate or a NOR gate takes 4 transistors e.g. a NOR gate looks like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUPm7l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For a NOT remove M2 and M4, for a NAND put M3 and M4 in parallel and M1 and M2 in series.

There are some optimizations you can do for more complex structures but hopefully you can see how by using these building blocks you can make any logic gates or function you want.

Comment: this make things more clear and simple . but i have no idea about those things in the schema , any reference from scratch ?

Comment: Would it be fair to include nand/nor gates?  If one needs to compute !((a & b) | (c & d)), one could compute it as !(!(!a | !b) & !(!c | !d)) but it would generally be more efficient to use an eight-transistor hybrid gate.

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi Have you read the WiKi page for a "Field-effect transistor"? There are tons of references at the bottom of that page.

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi: A transistor with an arrow pointing inward to the middle will connect the source and drain (top and bottom) if the gate (the thing entering from the left) is more positive than *both* of them; one with the arrow pointing outward from the middle will connect the source and drain if the gate is more *negative* than *both* source and drain.

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi A FET is the smallest building block in a digital chip. While they can act as amplifiers or to give a controlled gain in these circuits they are basically acting as a switch. The bottom ones switch on when their input is high, the top ones switch on when their input is low. Google can give you far more information than you will ever need on exactly how they work.

Comment: @supercat I'd consider hybrid gates as included under "There are some optimizations you can do for more complex structures".

Comment: @supercat Gate must be more positive than *both* source and drain ?? N... No.

Comment: @dim: Oops... the lower of source or drain.  The key point is that a normal FET won't be on when all three points are near the same voltage, so a FET with a positive gate will mainly be useful for connecting things to the negative rail, and a FET with a negative rail will be useful for connecting things to the positive rail.